# How to upgrade PHP 7.0.27 to 7.3 on Google Cloud?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to upgrade the current version of PHP (7.0.2) to 7.3.

I have tried this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316056/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-7-0-to-7-3-on-google-cloud-platform) which helped me install v7.3, but it does not get activated.

Here's what else I tried:

- I stopped and started VM Instance
- I restarted apache2
- Tried locating app.yaml to modify the PHP runtime specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime), but couldn't find it.
- I tried reinstalling apache since it was giving some error

But none of these helped. I also [read here](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/36288097-updating-php) that it's not possible without migrating to a new instance, which truly is a pain and I would want to avoid that at all costs.

Now sure what I should share so here are some stuff:
This is what I get for php -v

```html
$ php -v

PHP 7.0.27 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2018 12:12:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.27, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Am I missing out on something very obvious?

I am not much of a coder, so be gentle :P

Answer (score 2):

In your `app.yaml` add:

```
runtime: php73
```

[GCP - PHP 7 Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime)

Comment: Thanks. But I am not able to locate this file. I searched and found php.yaml, but nothing as app.yaml. Should I create one?

Comment: I was able to locate the file, added the runtime: php73, and yet it did not work.

-- 
application: bamboo-machine-422
version: 2
runtime: php73
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: call_compute_service_from_gae.app